# A better alternative to UI design in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, wysiwyg, designer

I got a app design project, I've been struggling with DroidDraw, is a non-usable UI tool from a designer perspective.

I need a tool that supports Android 4.0 UI elements, not a mockup tool like Balsamiq or such.

Does anyone know another alternatives to UI design with WYSIWYG editors that let you design and get the XML code?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For user interface designing you can use either [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-42/junor) or [Intellij Leda Preview](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+12+EAP)

For both of them you will need to install android sdk. More info [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html)

If you are using eclipse then you will have to install ADT plugin. More info [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html). Eclipse is officially supported by android.

Intellij comes with bundled android support. So you will not have to install any plugin for that.

Both of them are java IDE with android UI designer. They are not just UI designer as that of droid draw. To see what you will get from Intellij follow this [link](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/06/android-ui-designer-coming-in-intellij-idea-12/)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It seems that ForgeUI https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/1237?1023499612 could achieve what I'm looking for from a Designer perspective but no tried yet.